Implementing Role-Based Cache with Content Delivery Networks
We currently utilize Akamai caching for our content caching needs and now require support for role-based caching. Is it feasible to achieve this? I've been exploring EdgeWorkers, which seem capable of routing and enabling the creation of distinct services for specific cases. However, for certain scenarios, we need to implement role-based caching within the same service. I'm uncertain if EdgeWorkers can accommodate this requirement alongside caching functionalities
